# TableViewCell deleted then All checkmarks disappear on swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I searched the web for my problem but nothing helped in my case. It's kind of special.

My App has a checklist feature, everything is working fine but there is this problem. When adding a `checkmark` on the `UITableViewCell` and delete one of the other cells after that. All `checkmarks` will be deleted.

My thought was that the array and the connection have problems when something is getting deleted. I mean the "order" of properties in the array. I asked my coworkers (IT) but nobody could help me.

```
class ViewControllerChecklist: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (checklist.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 4 / 255.0, green: 59 / 255.0, blue: 101 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        cell.textLabel?.text = checklist[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    // checkmarks when tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            checklist.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 237 / 255.0, green: 108 / 255.0, blue: 4 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Cells selected
[image]

Hitting delete
[image]

Cell deleted
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out this code.

Store a selected value and compare at `UITableView` reloadData() time.

```
class ViewControllerChecklist: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    var selectedChecklist: [String] = []

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (checklist.count)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 4 / 255.0, green: 59 / 255.0, blue: 101 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        cell.textLabel?.text = checklist[indexPath.row]

        if selectedChecklist.contains(checklist[indexPath.row]) {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
        }
        else{
            cell.accessoryType = .none
        }

        return cell
    }

    // checkmarks when tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        selectedChecklist.append(checklist[indexPath.row])
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let value = checklist.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UITableViewCell.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 237 / 255.0, green: 108 / 255.0, blue: 4 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More simple solution is to make your checkList list of Objects add `isChecked` in your checkList.

```
struct Object {
    var tag:String
    var isChecked:Bool
}
```

And make list like this:

```
var checkList = [Object]()
```

finally in cellForRowAt function:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //  rest of code goes here...

    if checklist[indexPath.row].isChecked {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    checkList[indexPath.row].isChecked = true
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```